# How should I work with Column of Type List in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So for example I would like to do something like this:

```
  name                transport  price
0  AAA  [cars, bikes, airplane]    200
1  BBB    [boat, cars, walking]    100
2  CCC         [airplane, cars]     50
```

- Give me all of the rows and sum the price that have the transport (of type `list`) that contains`'airplane'` (group by).
  in this case it will return `250`

Should I convert the a column to a different data structure so it will be easier to work with the data?

---

PS: *I thought that I could use foreign keys (SQL) to work with the data, is this something pandas is capable of?*

PS: *I can't duplicate the rows as it will ruin the data (duplicating the price too).*

Comment: What do you want to do with your `transport` column? Do you need it to be read as a list, or a string that looks like a list? I think its the former to achieve your goal number 2. So you'll just need to create a new column that will provide the count of items in the list to obtain which name has the most transport.

Comment: use `df.explode('transport').reset_index(drop=True)` may be?

Comment: @anky_91 is it still reasonable if I have hunderands of items (it will result in hundreds of rows, and duplicates, no? - which I can't have)

Comment: Please add the expected output for the example input

Comment: @Joe will I lose anything by converting it to a comma separated string? It does sound achievable. And would I be able to group by only 'airplane' how would the query look like?

Comment: @funerr okay, for better understanding, please share the expected output and logic you want

Comment: @funerr i didnt understand this line: "I can't duplicate the rows as it will ruin the data (duplicating the price too)." explode returns a copy so you can work with that...?, check Daniel's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25) + [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
result = df.explode('transport').groupby('transport')['price'].sum()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
transport
airplane    250
bikes       200
boat        100
cars        350
walking     100
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

If you are not using pandas 0.25, use any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe).